# es2csv: found 0 results

Tags: csv, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the command line utility `es2csv` to export data from Elasticsearch into CSV file with the following syntax taken from github repo:

`es2csv -i logstash-2015-07-07 -q 'host: localhost' -o database.csv`

where `-i` indicates the Elasticsearch index to be exported, `-q` the host which I connect to, and `-o` the output file `.csv`. 
So in my case I run the following command:

`es2csv -i  enron_test -q 'http://localhost:9200' -o database.csv`

The problem is that this command returns `Found 0 results`, but I have some documents indexed into Elasticsearch database.

Anyone can solve this problem? Am I wrong in the syntax of the command? Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

-q is a query:
`-q, --query QUERY         Query string in Lucene syntax. [required]`
the host which you are connect to is -u:
`-u, --url URL             Elasticsearch host URL. Default is http://localhost:9200.`

Answer (score 0):

```
es2csv -u http://username:password@ip_address:9200/ \
  -r \
  -i "index_prefix_*" \
  -q '{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"exists":{"field":"uuid"}}}}}' \
  -m 100 \
  -o /tmp/filename.csv
 
 
 
Found 3100 results.
Run query [                                                                    ] [0/3100] [N/A%] [0:00:00] [ETA:  --:--:--] [  0.0 s/docs]Hit max result limit: 100 records
Write to csv [##############################################################] [100/100] [100%] [0:00:00] [Time: 0:00:00] [  4.1 Kilines/s]
Run query [################################################################] [3100/3100] [100%] [0:00:00] [Time: 0:00:00] [ 11.1 Kidocs/s]
```

`-q` is an option for es query.